# css error on the button bar of the post editor

Tags: bug, design, editor

I'm using Firefox 38 on vista. (Error still present now in FireFox 42 on vista.)
On [BSE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) (or any beta site) the error does not show up, however here and on SO (or anywhere with the new design) the "Markdown Editing Help" button in the post editor looks like this, if it pushed off the right edge. Do note it happens on the post editor for both questions and answers.
[image: post editor buttons]

[image: post editor with help open]

Comment: Reproduced here. Firefix 38 Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Firefox 36 on Win7-64 as well.

Comment: No repro on Chrome 43 OSX Yosemite...

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a Firefox-specific issue. For some reason, it automatically adds `left: 639px;` to the style of the containing `<li>`.